Всем привет. Кто поможет с задачей?(не получается попасть в лимит по времени)
Сама задача:

C. Тайное заклинание
Ограничение времени   1 секунда
Ограничение памяти    256Mb
Ввод
стандартный ввод или input.txt
Вывод
стандартный вывод или output.txt
Хината и Кенма играют в компьютерную игру. Для победы одному из них
необходимо одолеть всех магических существ другого. Игру можно
представить себе так:  n существ выстроены в ряд, i-е существо
обладает силой ai. Изначально все существа нейтральны, то есть не
принадлежат ни Хинате, ни Кенме. Хината может выбрать ровно k существ
и уничтожить их тайным заклинанием. После этого из оставшихся n−k
существ первая половина (стоящие в начале ряда существа) переходит на
сторону Хинаты, а вторая — на сторону Кенмы, после чего начинается
бой. Хината очень хочет победить. Для этого ему необходимо
максимизировать разность суммарной силы своих существ и существ Кенме,
то есть величину  D=(ai1+ai2+…+ai(n−k)∕2)−(ai(n−k)∕2+1+…+ain−k), где
i1,…,in−k — позиции существ, оставшихся после использования Хинатой
своей способности. Хината и Кенма собираются сыграть t игр. Помогите
Хинате — для каждой игры найдите максимальное D, которого он может
добиться.
Формат ввода
В первой строке входных данных задано единственное целое
число t(1≤t≤10) — количество игр. Далее следуют  t тестовых примеров,
разделённых переводом строки. В первой строке каждого тестового
примера через пробел заданы два целых числа n(2≤n≤3⋅10^5) и k(0≤k<n) —
число существ и количество существ, которых Хината уничтожит. Обратите
внимание, что Хината обязан использовать свою способность.
Гарантируется, что n−k — чётное число. Во второй строке каждого
тестового примера задано n целых чисел ai(1≤ai≤10^9) — силы
существ.Гарантируется, что сумма n по всем t не превосходит 3⋅10^5.
Формат вывода
Для каждого тестового примера на отдельной строке
выведите одно целое число  D — максимальную достижимую разность
суммарной силы существ Хинаты и Кенмы.

Вот мой код:

    for i in range(int(input())):
            nk = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
            tvary = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
            a = tvary[:len(tvary)//2]
            b = tvary[len(tvary)//2:]
            a.sort()
            b.sort()
            if nk[1] & 1:
                b = b[:-1]
                nk[1] -= 1
            for i in range(nk[1]//2): 
                b = b[:-1]
                a = a[1:]
            print(sum(a)-sum(b))


Как можно войти вовремя? Кто сможет подсказать?
(Нельзя использовать сторонние библиотеки.)

Ваш код точно решает задачу? Пусть a = [1, 3, 2], k = 1. Ваша программа вернёт -1 - она удалит 3. Лучшее решение 1 достигается удалением 1. Ускорять ошибочное решение неразумно.

Есть решение за nlogn через кучи.

@Stanislav Volodarskiy понял, сейчас исправлю

@Stanislav Volodarskiy к сожалению нельзя использовать сторонние библиотеки в данной задаче

Куча не стороняя библиотека. Если нельзя использовать стандартную, куча пишется в двадцать строк.

спасибо, что объяснил, надеюсь это мне поможет
